# SPFx: How to re-render my WebPart on section layout change

Tags: spfx

I'm trying to make my WebPart responsive to the column width in my section layout.
I get the width of the bounding rectangle by calling

```
const width: number = this.domElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

My render-function looks like this:

```
public render(): void {
    const width: number = this.domElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `<div>${width}</div>`;
}
```

When I insert my WebPart into the SharePoint workbench, the number 736 is shown.
However, if I change the layout of the section from one column to something else, the number doesn't change.

What do I need to do to trigger the render function as soon as the layout (and therefor the width) changes?

Comment: where you able to find solution for this?

Comment: no. The resize event is only relevant to resizing of the browser window and is not applicable to dom elements. I did add a resize event that triggers the render function when the size of the browser window changes, but i did not find a solution trigger the render function when the layout of the sharepoint page is changed.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you can create an event listener and in your function set the state to re-render your webpart:

```
private handleWindowSizeChange() {
  this.setState({
    size: window.innerWidth
  });
}
public componentDidMount() {
   window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowSizeChange.bind(this));
}
public componentWillUnmount() {
   window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleWindowSizeChange.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the window size is not changing when I change the layout of the section. Only the style of a div inside the side is changing, but I can't access the div because it's from the SharePoint layout and has no id.

Comment: You can create a div that envolves all your webpart (as I am sure that you have it) and do it the same but with the width of the element

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) api to listen for the layout change in the layout.

The only problem is that it is not supported by IE, Edge, and Safari.

```
public componentDidMount() {
    if(window.ResizeObserver) {
        this.resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(this.handleResize);
        this.resizeObserver.observe(this.domElement)
    }
}
public componentWillUnmount() {
    if(window.ResizeObserver) {
        this.resizeObserver.disconnect()
    }
}
```